Dual Boot Windows and other Operating Systems Order
I have BIOS firmware with MBR (512bytes first sector of the HD) (not UEFI/GPT).
I have the following Operating Systems:

Windows XP in primary partition
Sun Solaris 2008 in primary partition
PC-BSD (Unix) in primary partition
win2k3 in logical partition
Windows 7 in logical partition
RHEL 6 in logical partition
Fedora 16 in logical partition
And Swap logical partition.


I know that Windows Operating System Can be installed in Primary or Logical partition.
But predecessor of the Windows family must to be on the First primary partition.
For Example:
Windows 7 could be on the logical partition, But Windows XP or Win2k3 which are old Operating Systems (Older than Windows 7) must be on the first primary partition.

So my question is:

One of the Windows Operating system must be on the first primary partition? Is it a must in BIOS/MBR?
What will happen if Windows XP Will be in the second primary partition and Open Solaris for instance will be in the first primary partition? (this is another variant of question same as my question 1
Could we install first in the 3 primary partitions Linux operating system and in the extended one install Windows Operating system, For instance Windows XP?

Thanks!

Is there a reason you are not simply using hardware virtualization? Why the overly complicated partition setup?

@Ramhound The Motivation is to deeply understand and dive into the BOOT process of the Operating systems. (It's one of the books that i'm reading - Hands-on Booting.


One of the Windows Operating system must be on the first primary partition? Is it a must in BIOS/MBR?

The BIOS does not care either way, but if you want to boot Windows then the Windows requirements apply.
If I understand the situation correctly, it is specifically the Windows-provided MBR that cannot jump to a logical partition's VBR, meaning that the WinXP/2003 "NTLDR" needs to be on a primary partition – but during the second stage, NTLDR itself should be capable of loading the Windows kernel from a logical partition. (No guarantees though, I only did a quick skim of the source code.)
Other operating systems may not have such restrictions. For example, if you instead write Solaris's boot sector to the MBR instead, it'll load GRUB in a very different way.

What will happen if Windows XP Will be in the second primary partition and Open Solaris for instance will be in the first primary partition?

At first, the disk's initial boot sector which is in your MBR decides what to boot. If you are using the standard Windows boot sector, it will boot whichever primary partition is marked 'active' or 'bootable'. The MS-DOS and Syslinux boot sectors do the same.
That partition's own boot sector (VBR) may then boot an OS directly or it may show a boot menu like GRUB or NTLDR does.
On the other hand, if you're using the GRUB boot sector from Linux or Solaris, it will ignore partition flags and will always jump to its specific GRUB installation, which will show a boot menu.
